# jQuery Validation plugin remote rule changes php function value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-validate

I have an "edit user form" in order to change user data when needed. One of those fields is id number. I use the jQuery Validation plugin besides Codeigniter's form validation library.

I have this php function in my admin to check if the id entered for the user already exists on the database. If the id matches the one that user has stored on database then it's fine. BUt when trying to put another user's id, then an error shows up. If trying to enter an id that it's not stored on the database then it should be ok and no error should be displayed.

I build a php function for this which is working fine. Problem is when doing the jquery function to call that php function.

Here's the view:

```
<div class="span6">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">N&uacute;mero<span class="required">*</span></label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="documentn" id="documentn" class="m-wrap span8" value="{$frontuser->document}" required/>
            <span class="help-block"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jquery function:

```
documentn: {
  required: true,
  minlength: 7,
  maxlength: 20,
  remote: {
  url: '/admin/checkDocAndUser',
  type: 'POST',
   },  
 },
```

Here's php function:

```
public function checkDocAndUser(){
    if ((isset($_POST['documentn'])) && (isset($_POST['id']))) {
        $n = $_POST['documentn'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $dn = UserManager::getInstance()->checkUserDocument($n,$id);
        if ($dn) {
            //id belongs to the user
            echo "true";
        }else{
            //does the id entered belongs to another user?
            $exists = UserManager::getInstance()->getByDocument($_POST['documentn']);
            if (!$exists) {
                // number entered belongs to another user
                echo "false";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so given the php function works when I don't use the js validation file...why jquery function is not working?

I have tried changing remote's rule url to: admin/checkDocAndUser, /checkDocAndUser, checkDocAndUser but doesn't work.

**EDIT AND WORKING**

considered what @Sparky said, and now I'm sending user id

```
documentn: {
  required: true,
  minlength: 7,
  maxlength: 20,
  remote: {
    url: '/admin/checkDocAndUser',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
     id: function(){
     var dn = $('#id').val();
     return dn;
    }                                
   } 
  }
},

public function checkDocAndUser(){
    if ((isset($_POST['documentn'])) && (isset($_POST['id']))) {
        $dn = UserManager::getInstance()->checkUserDocument($_POST['documentn'],$_POST['id']);
        if ($dn) {
            //id belongs to the user
            echo "true";
        }else{
            //does the id entered belong to another user?
            $exists = UserManager::getInstance()->getByDocument($_POST['documentn']);
            if (!$exists) {
                // number entered belongs to another user
                echo "true";
            }else{
                echo "false";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are specifically talking about the jQuery Validation plugin.  The jQuery library does not contain a `remote` method or any validation whatsoever.  Are you including the plugin?

Comment: @Sparky yes I'm including every plugin. This remote rule works fine in other fields, for example for checking if username is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  Verify that you're including the jQuery Validation plugin on the page.  It needs to be included just after the jQuery library.

2)  In your PHP function, you seem to be looking for **two** POST inputs: `if ((isset($_POST['documentn'])) && (isset($_POST['id'])))`.  However, by default the `remote` method only sends the data from the field you're validating, `documentn`.  If you need the value from another field to be sent along, then you need to configure it using the `data` option in `remote`...

```
documentn: {
    required: true,
    // minlength: 7,     // <- can be replaced with rangelength rule
    // maxlength: 20,    // <- can be replaced with rangelength rule
    rangelength: [7,20], // <- can be used in place of two rules
    remote: {            // <- by default, only posts data from 'documentn' field       
        url: '/admin/checkDocAndUser',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {          // <- also post data from another field(s)
            anotherfield: function() {  // <- post name, $_POST['anotherfield']
                return $( "#another_field" ).val();
            }
        }
    }  
},
```

3) I'm not sure about the logic in your `checkDocAndUser` function.  What happens when it does not belong to other user and it exists?  You're not echoing anything in that case.  The `remote` method needs a `true` when validation should pass and a `false`, `undefined`, or `null` when it should fail.  If it echoes a JSON string, then it fails and the string becomes the error message.  Verify that your logic is doing what you intended [as per the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).

See docs:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: so I used the data field in order to get the user id. How do I "catch" it in php function instead of using POST['id']?

Comment: @Limon, you just use the same thing as before `$_POST['id']`.  The `data` option is sending it along just like any other ordinary form POST.

Comment: @Limon, I'm using it and it works.  I cannot imagine what's going wrong for you.  The path to the server-side script is relative to the location of the JavaScript.  Verify the URL with the browser and check the CodeIgniter routes.

Comment: @Limon, in my CodeIgniter controller, I'm using `$this->input->post('name')`, etc.

Comment: it's weird because it works if I don't call the js file. I'll keep trying

Comment: @Limon, please more carefully look at the code in my answer and my comments.  `documentn` is ***already*** being sent as part of the default remote rule.  Your ***other*** POST data point goes inside of `data`.  In your edited OP, you're sending `id` as `documentn`.

Comment: oh, you are right. So I've this id hidden field in the form... now I changed function name to userid: function(){ //code  or do I need to have this field in my jquery rules?

Comment: @Limon, that seems right.  Then if you call it `userid`, the POST would be the same.  Again, look at comments in my example.  `$_POST['userid']`, **not** `$_POST['id']`.

Comment: I get it ;) I'm trying and I let you know soon

Comment: I could not do it without you @Sparky. I truly understand this logic now. I adjusted my php function also because I realized the query was inverted (returning false instead of a true). thank you.